# Help on second order linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. Find the solution of the given initial value problem:

   $y'' + 8y' -9y = 0, y(2)=1, y'(2)=0$

   What I did was solve the characteristic equation and then I got the solution to the   homogeneous equation: $y(x)= {C1e}^x + {C2e}^{-9x}$, but I'm not sure how to solve it with the initial conditions.
2. Solve the initial value problem $y''-y'-2y=0, y(0)= \alpha, y'(0)=2$. Then find $\alpha$ so that the solution approaches zero as t becomes infinity.

This problem is more challenging for me. What I tried to do here was solve the characteristic equation which gave me $y(t)=C1{e}^{2t} + C2{e}^{-t}$. Then I found 
$y'(t)=2{C1e}^{2x} {-C2e}^{-x}$
so then I used the initial conditions and I got:

$C1 + C2 = \alpha$

$2C1 -C2 = 2$

and by inspection of the general solution it seems that only way this will approach $0$ is if $C1 = 0$ since there is no way that $e^{2t}$ will ever be zero, but $e^-t$ will. So does $\alpha = -2$?

Any tips/solution would be appreciated :)

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations in detail but (ii) looks right to me.  For (i), do it in exactly the same way as (ii)!  Just one thing for (ii): make sure you use the variable $t$ or $x$ consistently.

Comment: yeah I tried on i) just now, but im awful at algebra and failed :( idk what to do when I dont have y(0)=c if you know what I mean :P

Comment: Actually I didn't notice it was $y(2)$ instead of $y(0)$. . . That does make it harder but it's still really the same, you just have to substitute $x=2$ to get conditions for $C_1$ and $C_2$ and then be very careful with the algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first one, you found a good solution:

$$y(x)= c_1e^x + c_2e^{-9x}$$

Now, you have two unknowns, so you need two equations in order to solve for those constants. You are given $y(2)=1, y'(2)=0$, so we use this to set up and solve those two equations and determine $c_1$ and $c_2$. Using the first initial condition, , $y(2) = 1$, we have (just substitute):

$$y(2) = c_1 e^2 + c_2 e^{-18} = 1$$

Using the second initial condition, $y'(2) = 0$, we first need to find the derivative and then substitute, so we have

$$y(x)= c_1e^x + c_2e^{-9x} \implies y'(x) = c_1e^x - 9 c_2e^{-9x}$$

We can now substitute $y'(2) = 0$ and have:

$$ y'(2) = c_1e^2 - 9 c_2e^{-18} = 0$$

Now, we have the $2\times 2$ system:

$$c_1 e^2 + c_2 e^{-18} = 1 \\ c_1e^2 - 9 c_2e^{-18} = 0$$

Use your favorite method (Elimination, Cramer's Rule, Gaussian Elimination...) to solve that $2x2$, yielding:

$$c_1 = \dfrac{9}{10e^2}, c_2 = \dfrac{e^{18}}{10}$$

The final result is (you can clean it up a bit, but left this way on purpose):

$$y(x)= \dfrac{9}{10e^2}~e^x + \dfrac{e^{18}}{10}~e^{-9x}$$

We repeat the same process for the second equation:

$$y''-y'-2y=0, y(0)= \alpha, y'(0)=2$$

Again you found the correct solution as:

$$y(t)=c_1e^{2t} + c_2e^{-t}$$

So, we repeat the above steps to get (note: $y'(t) = 2c_1e^{2t} -c_2e^{-t}$):

$$y(0) = c_1  + c_2  = \alpha \\ y'(0) = 2c_1-c_2 = 2$$

Solving this $2x2$, yields:

$$c_1 = \dfrac{\alpha + 2}{3}, c_2 = \dfrac{2(\alpha -1)}{3}$$

Our final result is:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{\alpha + 2}{3}~e^{2t} + \dfrac{2(\alpha -1)}{3}~e^{-t}$$

We now want to find $\alpha$ such that the solution approaches zero as $t \rightarrow \infty$, so you are correct, we need to get rid of the $e^{2t}$ term. We can let $\alpha = -2$, so that leaves:

$$y(t) =  -2~e^{-t}$$